# Is there any good survey on the hook length formula and related topics?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

I am recently doing some research related to the hook length formula.
The hook formula counts the number of Young tableaux of certain type.

I find there are plenty of research already been done and I can observe a lot extension and generalization of hook length formula types. But is there a good survey on those research and open problems?

What I am interested are those extensions purely combinatorial, but it is still good if anybody can provide some survey on the representation theory side.

Please correct me if there are easy-to-find survey or the problem is too general for asking.

Comment: Do you already know about Bruce Sagan's book *The Symmetric Group*?

Comment: There's a triad of papers -- http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0043 , http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1865 , http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.4593 -- which seems to cover a lot of ground (no, I have not read them). Two other approaches appear in http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/hl7.ps and http://web.mit.edu/~shopkins/docs/rsk.pdf . I also remember having seen a review paper appear on the arXiv about counting Young tableaux (or P-partitions? or increasing maps between posets?) which includes the hook length formula and lots of other results (but mostly without proof).

Comment: a good 2-page intro with references to books is here: http://www.ams.org/notices/200702/whatis-yong.pdf

Comment: I believe C. Krattenthaler has some nice proofs of the classical formulas. There is also the notion of hook-formulas for counting linear extensions of certain posets, (Forests, D-complete posets).
See the work of Proctor for the latter, http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/rap/

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Thanks, this is exact what kind of related topics I found.

Comment: Of course the standard reference would be Chapter 7 of Stanley's EC2. It does not spend too much time on the hook-length formula but everyone interested in this kind of combinatorics should read this chapter anyways.

Comment: Per's link now points to an article about rap music...

Answer (score 5):

Some references you might find interesting:

Proctor classify certain posets (d-complete posets), that admit hook formulas. There are hook formulas for forests, as well as some [other types](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Ereiner/Talks/Ppartitions.pdf). (Victor Reiner, *P-partitions revisited*, Triangle Lectures in Combinatorics slides, 2011.)

Also, I believe there is some [recent results on hook formulas for skew shapes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08348). (Morales, Pak, Panova, *Hook formulas for skew shapes I*, 2015.)